# Golod-Shafarevich groups and L_2- Betti numbers

Tags: gr.group-theory, fa.functional-analysis, cohomology

Is it something known about $L^2$-Betti numbers for Golod-Shafarevich groups?

Comment: Did you see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.2202.pdf, Appendix B, and references there? If it is not what you are looking for, you can ask Misha Ershov directly.